# C# invoke a webmethod

Tags: c#, webmethod, params-keyword

i am using a webmethod with uses the params keyword.   (params int[] par)

can i test this webmethod via a browser ?
-> how to write this url to invoke the webmethod  (e.g. with 6 arguments) ?

Comment: You can't do that via URL, you must Post the values. You can write small web application just for testing the service, shouldn't take more than 20-30 minutes.

Comment: Shadow Wizard: You get the point. Yes, using a browser (test site) for an argument such as List<float> isn't possible.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by that.. what exactly do you want then?

Comment: hi, it wasn't sardonic. ;-) i wasn't sure (nov. 27th) about testing a service via the browser with non-primitive datatypes. the short answer to my question (test via webbrowser) would be a 'NO' and you explained it correct.

Comment: Cheers, added it as answer now so it would be more visible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that via URL, you must Post the values.

You can write small web application just for testing the service, shouldn't take more than 20-30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a web reference to your project, using the URL of your web service.

This will generate a proxy class that will let you call the web methods from your code.

- [How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx)
- [How to: Call a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h0yh8f9.aspx)

---

Invoking a web method will normally involve SOAP, so the query string is not an option. You may be able to do so with AJAX calls, but this is time consuming and error prone.

Is there a reason the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) is not good enough?

Comment: is it possible to test it via a browser ? (this was my question)

Comment: @Monkey - Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519199/wcf-webservices-where-has-the-browser-test-form-gone/1519214#1519214