# WCF Services, Can I view output in a browser?

Tags: c#, web-config, wcf

I feel like this question is so basic that none of the tutorials or documentation even bothers to mention how to do it. I'm familiar with web services on other platforms, but I'm new to WCF services.

I've set up a wsHttpBinding like this (in the web.config):

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="IdentityServiceBehavior" name="Com.CompanyName.Service.IdentityService">
    <endpoint address="/Identityservice" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="Com.CompanyName.Service.IIdentityService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          bindingNamespace="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

I attempt to hit the URL using Fiddler or just a browser and it just gives me a 400 result. I've tried a bunch of different possibilities for what the URL might be, but no dice. I've tried this URL and a few variations on it: http://localhost:61987/IdentityService.svc/Identityservice

If anyone could point me in the direction of the basic information I'm missing here, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What happens if you simply open the .svc url in a browser? If that doesn't come up and show you the WCF screen, your server may not be configured correctly.

Comment: I get the default page that says, "You have created a service. To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax..."

Comment: Also, calling IdentityService.svc?wsdl gives me a good XML response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Webservices, where has the browser test form gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519199/wcf-webservices-where-has-the-browser-test-form-gone)

Comment: @TrueWill thanks, I think this is the information I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WCF test client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to test your WCF services